# CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek returns sunday?

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

Running this command

```
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek
```

in C# returns Sunday.

It should return Monday.

Why does it return Sunday?

Comment: Why do you think it _should_ return Monday?

Comment: Your assertion is plainly incorrect.

Comment: It follows the Jewish way to count the days of the week, so the week ends on Sabbat (Saturday)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OPs original assertion is incorrect.

Comment: Start day of work week and software weeks _can_ be different concepts. From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar#Week: _Opinions vary about the numbering of the days of the week. ISO 8601, in common use worldwide, starts with Monday=1; printed monthly calendar grids list Mondays in the first (left) column of dates and Sundays in the last_. **Software often starts with** _Sunday=0, which places Sundays in the left column of a monthly calendar page_. You said _It should return Monday_ but you didn't _even_ explain _why_ it should. ++

Comment: ++ This is similar as: "This program says UNICORNS are real but they should be unreal" but you didn't even explain or prove why. Since we all know, they ARE real.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned on this page

[The Week and its Seven Days](http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/days/)

> According to the international standard ISO 8601, Monday is the first
>   day of the week ending with Sunday as the seventh day of the week.
>   Although this is the international standard, countries such as the
>   United States still have their calendars refer to Sunday as the start
>   of the seven-day week.

Thus your assumption that the US culture should have Monday returned via `DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek` is incorrect.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date):

> Not all parts of the world consider the week to begin with Monday. For
>   example, in some Muslim countries, the normal work week begins on
>   Saturday, while in Israel it begins on Sunday. In the US, although the
>   work week is usually defined to start on Monday, the week itself is
>   often considered to start on Sunday.